# How to analyze first-order transient circuits using Simulink?

Tags: capacitor, simulation, transient, simulink, steady-state

I have been trying to design a first-order circuit with a capacitor but, I could't achieve to initaliaze the steady-state condition. I mean I was not able to close the switch at t = 0. Since, I am using a dc voltage source, at t = 0 capacitor voltage must be equal steady-state value. My question is how can I achieve that?[image: This the circuit which I am trying to obey.]

Could you tell me which block should I use ın Simulink?

This is the circuit that ı had designed
[image: This is the circuit that ı had designed.]

Comment: Simulink is overkill .  You can choose any initial voltage in Falstad.

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/y24qex7h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with these questions is t=0 does not imply that at t=0 the power is also applied, they imply t=-∞ the power supplies are "turned on" and a steady-state condition is achieved.

This is crucial when you consider how simulations work since they typically by default initialize with current and voltage all at zero and thus if a switch is commanded at t=0 the result mentioned in the question will occur, no matter the simulation engine used.

Different simulation packages solve this in different way and one of them is performing a DC bias point "pre simulation". Simulink is no different but how you solve this is up to you and upto "convinience"

Without doing anything this is the results
[image]

**OPTION #1**
redefine t=0 to be t=TBD where TBD is determined via separate simulation, ~ 3.3seconds.

[image]
In this instance you can see at t=5 the step is enabled

**OPTION #2**
If you determine the DC bias point (separate simulation), you can set the initial voltage on the capacitors and have a step time of t=0

[image]

Comment: I am so appriciated for your answer. But can I ask you which value you have assigned for the series resistor parameter in the capacitor ?